# Ruby regex to extract a number from string containing only one number and trim the part after comma

Tags: regex, ruby, numbers, currency, number-formatting

I have a method to extract number from a string using regex, like that:

```rb
def format 
  str = "R$ 10.000,00 + Benefits"
  str.split(/[^\d]/).join
end
```

Its returns --> `1000000`. I need to modfy regex to return `10000`, removing zeros after comma.

Comment: `str.gsub(/(?<=\d),\d+|\D/, '')`? Or really only zeros? Then `str.gsub(/(?<=\d),0++(?!\d)|\D/, '')`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you're a regex wizard! Could you please explain the `?<=`? Thanks a lot!

Comment: ```str.gsub(/(?<=\d),\d+|\D/, '')``` Works like a charm.

Comment: What if there are multiple numbers in the string? `str = "Joe paid $ 10.000,00, but Jane got the better deal for $ 7.900,00"` Removing all decimal digits and non-digits will leave you with `100007900`. Or does that scenario never happen?

Comment: If not evident from @3limin4t0r's comment, the problem occurs if there are any other digits in the string, not just representations of dollar amounts: `"On October 7 Joe paid $ 10.000,00".split(/[^\d]/).join #=> "71000000`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
str.gsub(/(?<=\d),\d+|\D/, '')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YuuCpC/1).

**Regex details**

- `(?<=\d),\d+` - a comma that is immediately preceded with a digit (`(?<=\d)` is a positive lookbehind) and then one or more digits
- `|` - or
- `\D` - any non-digit symbol

One important aspect is that you should order these alternatives like this, `\D` must be used as the last alternative. Else, `\D` can match a `,` and the solution won't work.

Comment: `"On October 7 Joe paid R$ 10.000,00.".gsub(/(?<=\d),\d+|\D/, '') #=> "710000"`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland The strings OP has only contain one numeric value to get.

Answer (score 2):

```
str = "R$ 10.000,00 R$1.200.000,03 R$ 0,09 R$ 4.00,10 R$ 3.30005,00 R$ 6.700 R$ 6, R$ 6,0 R$ 00,20 R$6,001 US$ 5.122,00 Benefits"
```

```
R = /(?:(?<=\bR\$)|(?<=\bR\$ ))(?:0|[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:\.\d{3})*),\d{2}(?!\d)/
```

```
str.scan(R).map { |s| s.delete('.') }
  #=> ["10000,00", "1200000,03", "0,09"]
```

None of the following substrings match because they have invalid formats: `"4.00,10"`, " `3.30005,00"`, `"6.700"`, `"6,"`, `"6,0"`, `"00,20"`, `"6,001"` and `"5.122,00"` (the last because it is not preceded by `"$R"` or `"$R "`.

The regular expression can be written in *free-spacing mode* (`/x`) to make it self-documenting.

```
R = /
    (?:            # begin non-capture group
      (?<=\bR\$)   # positive lookbehind asserts match is preceded by 'R$'
                   #   that is preceded by a word break
      |            # or
      (?<=\bR\$\ ) # positive lookbehind asserts match is preceded by 'R$ '
                   #   that is preceded by a word break
    )              # end non-capture group
    (?<=           # begin negative lookbehind 
      $R[ ])       #  asserts that match is preceded by a space
    (?:            # begin non-capture group
      0            # match zero
      |            # or
      [1-9]        # match a digit other than zero
      \d{0,2}      # match 0-2 digits
      (?:\.\d{3})  # match '.' followed by three digits in a non-capture group 
      *            # execute preceding non-capture group 0+ times
    )              # end non-capture group
    ,\d{2}         # match ',' followed by two digits
    (?!\d)         # negative lookahead asserts match is not followed by a digit
    /x
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly longer, but perhaps simpler and easier to understand solution. You can use it as an alternative to the excellent and concise answer by *Wiktor Stribiżew*, and the very thorough and complete answer by *Cary Swoveland*. Note that my answer may not work for some (more complex) strings, as mentioned in the comment by *Cary* below.

```
str = "R$ 10.000,00 + Benefits"
puts str.gsub(/^.*?(\d+[\d.]*).*$/, '\1').gsub(/[.]/, '')
# => 10000
```

Here [`gsub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-gsub) is applied to the input string twice:

1. `gsub(/^.*?(\d+[\d.]*).*$/, '\1')` : grab `10.000` part.
   `^` is the beginning of the string.
   `.*?` is any character repeated 0 or more times, non-greedy (that is, minimum number of times).
   `(\d[\d.]*)` is any digit followed by digits or literal dots (`.`). The parenthesis capture this and put into the first capture group (to be used later as `'\1'` as the replacement string).
   `.*` is any character repeated 0 or more times, greedy (that is, as many as possible).
   `$` is the end of the string.
   Thus, we replace the entire string with the first captured group: `'\1'`, which is `10.000` here. Remember to use single quotes around `\1`, otherwise escape it twice like so: `"\\1"`.
2. `gsub(/[.]/, '')` : remove all literal dots (`.`) in the string.

---

Note that this code does the expected replacements for a number of similar strings (but nothing fancier, such as leaves `001` as is):

```
['R$ 10.000,00 + Benefits',
 'R$      0,00 + Benefits',
 'R$   .001,00 + Benefits',
 '.  10.000,00 + Benefits',].each do |str|
  puts [str, str.gsub(/^.*?(\d+[\d.]*).*$/, '\1').gsub(/[.]/, '')].join(" => ")
end
```

Output:

```
R$ 10.000,00 + Benefits => 10000
R$      0,00 + Benefits => 0
R$   .001,00 + Benefits => 001
.  10.000,00 + Benefits => 10000
```

Comment: `"On October 7 Joe paid R$ 10.000,00.".gsub(/^.*?(\d+[\d.]*).*$/, '\1').gsub(/[.]/, '') #=> "7"`

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thank you for pointing out the incorrect parsing of some strings in my answer.